# Xdebug integration with PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I've tested installation of Xdebug with `var_dump()` and it is installed but I can't make it to work with my Laravel project.

This is my `/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini`:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9003 #if you want to change the port you can change
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

and this is my `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini`:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
```

And this is my PhpStorm config:

[image]

[image]

What else can I do to have Xdebug working with PhpStorm?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be running Xdebug 3.x, while using the settings for Xdebug 2.

With Xdebug 3.x, nearly all of the settings that you have used are replaced with new names. Please read the [Upgrade Guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide).